# JQuery Toggle Hide/ Show with Plus and Minus Images and Text

Tags: jquery

Reigel's code works like a champ on JSFiddle. But won't do anything for me. What could I be Missing? I believe I have the proper tags and a link to the relevant version of the JQuery Library.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JQuery Show/ Hide Cart- Working??!!- Mine</title>
<style type="text/css">
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script language="javascript">
 $(".toggle").click(function(){
  $(".hidden").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).find('img').attr('src',function(i,src){
        return (src.indexOf('plusSign.gif') != -1)? 'minusSign.gif' : 'plusSign.gif';
    })
}); 


    $(".toggle").click(function(){
  $(".hidden").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).html(function(i,html) {
            if (html.indexOf('Show') != -1 ){
               html = html.replace('Show','Hide');
            } else {
               html = html.replace('Hide','Show');
            }
            return html;
        }).find('img').attr('src',function(i,src){
        return (src.indexOf('plus.png') != -1)? 'http://t1.gstatic.com/images?    q=tbn:1PS9x2Ho4LHpaM:http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/minus.png' :'http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:4TZreCjs_a1eDM:http://www.venice.coe.int/images/plus.png';
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p class="toggle">Show Panel <img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:4TZreCjs_a1eDM:http://www.venice.coe.int/images/plus.png"></p>
<div class="hidden"> Blah Blah Blah </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: CodeIgnoto, absolutely nothing. It just sits there like a ,jpg I will provide a link. here is the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/RKsEm/    and my copied and pasted version: http://funlifefoods.com/Cart_Show_Hide_Working.php Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put all your jquery code inside document ready so that the code is only executed when the document has loaded ex

```
$(function(){
//all you code now
$(".toggle").click(function(){
  $(".hidden").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).find('img').attr('src',function(i,src){
        return (src.indexOf('plusSign.gif') != -1)? 'minusSign.gif' : 'plusSign.gif';
    })
}); 


    $(".toggle").click(function(){
  $(".hidden").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).html(function(i,html) {
            if (html.indexOf('Show') != -1 ){
               html = html.replace('Show','Hide');
            } else {
               html = html.replace('Hide','Show');
            }
            return html;
        }).find('img').attr('src',function(i,src){
        return (src.indexOf('plus.png') != -1)? 'http://t1.gstatic.com/images?    q=tbn:1PS9x2Ho4LHpaM:http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/minus.png' :'http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:4TZreCjs_a1eDM:http://www.venice.coe.int/images/plus.png';
    });
});

});
```

read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Thanks so much Parv! Very grateful. You got it working for the most part.. it just doesn't switch from the plus sign to the minus sign.

Comment: It also, will not stay in Open/ Down State.

Comment: Thanks Parv!!! Just reposted uncommented js code from JSFiddle below your first line of: $(function(){
//all you code now